# Multiple long polling?

Tags: ajax, long-polling

I'm developing a chat application and I've come across the following thought.. Should I use 'multiple' long polling requests to my server, each one handling different things. For example one checking for messages, one for 'is typing', one for managing the contacts list 'is online/offline' etc.. or would it be better to handle it all through one channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling is going to be your biggest bandwidth/resource hog, so keep it to a minimum; e.g. issue HEAD requests with appropiate date / if-modified-since headers to allow caching to work sensibly, with the server returning just headers containing the date and time of the last change to *any* of the properties you're interested in - or perhaps something even more minimal than that; and only issue a full GET if the returned headers imply there is new information.

Comment: Yes. The PHP end will have to check the request method and only return the headers (otherwise there's no benefit!)

Comment: Right! Maybe I'm missing something but in this example PHP checks for new information (at a set interval) and then if there is - returns it to the ajax polling request.. so why ask for a header first and then grab new data?

Comment: You need to minimise the traffic crossing the net. The idea is the JS in the browser makes just a tiny request and the PHP makes a tiny response, unless there's new data. Now, you *could* roll your own protocol here (e.g. JS issues regular request, PHP returns a response with just the new data), but if you use HTTP correctly (JS issues HEAD request / GET request with correct if-modified-since header, PHP responce is just headers or full body as appropriate and the last-modified date correct), you're working with caches rather than fighting against them, and traffic is reduced even further.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is that you’d be better off with one connection, and sending JSON messages back and forth, e.g.:

#### User joined:

```
{"user_add": "st3"}
```

#### User left:

```
{"user_left": "sneeu"}
```

#### Message received

```
{"message": "Good morning!", "from": "st3"}
```

And these could be sent together in an array, so that users could receive everything since their last response.

Comment: This seems sensible, multiple polling was probably overkill! Thanks